# how do i remove ' ' [ ] in array (python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i have this code:

```
dfx = pd.read_csv('hasil_processing_auto.csv', encoding='unicode_escape')
dy = dfx.loc[:,'polarity']
X = dy.values

print(X)
```

and this is the output i get:

```
['[0]' '[0]' '[0]' '[0]' '[0]' '[0]' '[0]' '[0]' '[0]' '[0]' '[0]' '[0]'
 '[1]' '[0]' '[0]' '[0]' '[0]' '[0]' '[0]' '[1]']
```

i want it to be just like `[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]`

the csv is like this:

```
    tweets                                              label   polarity
0   i love myself kuliah tugas tumpuk sapu ngepel ...   Netral  [0]
1   suogh online online kuliah                          Netral  [0]
2   bisnis sekolah kuliah ngantor online shop prod...   Netral  [0]
3   tunggu surat putus rektor surat putus dekan la...   Netral  [0]
4   kuliah online bosan                                 Netral  [0]
.....
```

Comment: Your list is evaluated to object type when reading. To read it properly as valid python list try `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: The `read_csv` loads those `[0]` column values as strings.  This sort of thing often occurs when you save a dataframe as `csv`, and the original frame had lists (or array) elements.  `csv` is best used when the dataframe has simple column elements - numbers and strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to strip the column as such:

```
'[0]'[1:-1] --> '0'
```

If you are new to Python, you can treat a `string` as an iterable so you can subset it by `[start:end]`

```
dfx['polarity'] = dfx['polarity'].apply(lambda x: x[1:-1])
```

Comment: got this output `['' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '']`

Comment: sorry got to be -1

Comment: I think he means -1